# Excel Pivot Table - Date Range Filter with Filter Dimension

Tags: filter, pivot-table, excel-2013, date-range, dimension

I have a date dimension in the FILTERS part of an Excel 2013 Pivot Table.
I want to easily filter for all the dates in a range but i have to check and uncheck tons of checkboxes while i would like to just specify two dates. I can do this when the dimension is in the ROWS but i can't understand how to do the same in filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a [Timeline filter](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Create-a-PivotTable-timeline-to-filter-dates-d3956083-01be-408c-906d-6fc99d9fadfa?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) instead of a regular filter or slicer?

You just need to have a field that is a date. Use it to create the timeline (on the Insert tab in Excel, choose Timeline). Then you can select the level/time period (date, month, quarter, year) at which you want to create your date range and click and drag to create the range.  More details are in the link.