# Excel timeline filter for date ranges, not date instances

Tags: excel, datetime, pivot-table

Lets say I have a hotel booking excel table with the following columns:
Start date,
End date,
Room number.

When I create a pivot table, I want to create a timeline filter that shows how many rooms are booked in the filtered range.

If I simply create a timeline filter for 'Start date', it won't really work: E.g. If a room is booked from 2020.10.10 to 2020.10.17 and I filter 2020.10.11, it won't include the room into the calculation, as its not the start date.

Comment: It would, if you have `Microsoft-365` and use `FILTER()` function.

Comment: Does this post [Excel Pivot Table - Date Range Filter with Filter Dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563611/excel-pivot-table-date-range-filter-with-filter-dimension) help?

Comment: Doesn't really help. I'm already using Timeline Filter. But the given example deals with date instances, not ranges.

Regarding the FILTER() function, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If not wrong, you should be restructuring the data. Since you already have `start date` and `end date`, I suggest you to make a new column `Booking Date` in which we need to list all the dates from the `start date` to `end date`  per booking.

- **Eg:** Let's say a room is booked between `1.1.2099` to `10.1.2099`, which will give one row for each date within the range per room number.

Now our fancy `pivot-table`, use `Booking Date` as your filter field. This way, when you filter for a specific date, it will include all the dates within the booking period for each room.

This should do for the required outcome.

- Example: We have two columns; `A` and `B`. If `A2` contains `10` and `B2` contains `15`, I want to fill `C2, that contains a series of numbers between the values in A2 and B2, separated by commas. So, the output in column C2 should be: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15.
  Here is a simple table for better understanding:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 |
| 10 | 13 | 10, 11, 12, 13 |
| 20 | 25 | 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 |

Now imagine the columns filled with dates and then the Booking date column, filled with necessary data. When you `pivot-table`, you have the option to filter or other operations.

Comment: Although that's a great idea, could you elaborate on how you would envision such a restructured dataset.

Let's say we have the following dataset
Start date  | End date   |          Booking date                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------
2023.01.01| 2023.01.10|How would this cell be populated? |

Would you create separate rows for each date in the range?

Comment: updated the answer, please check the example in the end

Comment: Nice to put the data into such format. But this will just make it complicated for other operations